# Microsoft SQL Query Get count of DISTINCT values using Over Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a Count for all the Distinct Case Sensitive values using Over Partition.

I have the following values:

```
FirstCol    SecCol

A           E
A           E
A           a
A           e
```

I want my results to be:

```
SecCol    FirstCol    SecColCount
a         A           1
e         A           1
E         A           2
```

I am trying to achieve this using the OVER PARTITION method below, but I am getting the following results with my Query:

```
SecCol    FirstCol    SecColCount
a         A           1
e         A           3
```

Here is the Query I am trying to use:

```
SELECT Distinct SecCol, FirstCol, 'SecColCount' = count(SecCol) OVER (PARTITION BY SecCol) 
FROM #LocalTempTable;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default collation for tempdb/db is case insensitive. Use case sensitive instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  SecCol COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as,
  FirstCol,
  [SecColCount] = COUNT(SecCol) OVER (PARTITION BY SecCol 
                                      COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as) 
FROM #LocalTempTable;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395668)**</kbd>